# Get sub-map from std::map by number of elements instead of key using iterator

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` and I need to perform a threaded task on this map by dividing the map into sub-maps and passing each sub-map to a thread.

With a `std::vector<T>` I would be able to get a sub-vector pretty easy, by doing this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    size_t off = 0; 
    size_t num_elms = 100; // Made up value 
    std::vector<uint8_t> full; // Assume filled with stuff
    std::vector<uin8t_t> sub(std::begin(full) + off, std::begin(full) + off + num_elms);
    off = off + num_elms;
}
```

However, doing the same with `std::map<T1, T2>` gives a compilation error.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    size_t off = 0; 
    size_t num_elms = 100; 
    
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> full; 
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> sub(std::begin(full) + off, 
                                                        std::begin(full) + off + num_elms); 
    off = off + num_elms;
}
```

It is the same with other `std::map` "types". Which, from what I have gathered, is down to the iterator.

What is possible is to extract the keys and do something similar to this solution:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

void print_map(const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& _map)
{
    for (const auto& [key, value] : _map)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << "\nvalues\n";
        for (const auto& elm : value)
        {
            std::cout << "\t" << elm << "\n"; 
        }
    }
}

void print_keys(const std::vector<std::string>& keys)
{
    std::cout << "keys: \n"; 
    for(const auto& key : keys)
    {
        std::cout << key << "\n"; 
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> full;

    full["aa"] = {"aa", "aaaa", "aabb"};
    full["bb"] = {"bb", "bbbbb", "bbaa"};
    full["cc"] = {"cc", "cccc", "ccbb"};
    full["dd"] = {"dd", "dd", "ddcc"};

    print_map(full);

    std::vector<std::string> keys;

    for (const auto& [key, value] : full)
    {
        (void) value;
        keys.emplace_back(key); 
    }

    print_keys(keys); 

    size_t off = 0;
    size_t num_elms = 2;
    
    
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> sub1 (full.find(keys.at(off)), full.find(keys.at(off + num_elms)));
    off = off + num_elms; 
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> sub2 (full.find(keys.at(off)), full.find(keys.at(off + num_elms -1)));

    std::cout << "sub1:\n";
    print_map(sub1);
    std::cout << "sub2:\n";
    print_map(sub2);     
}
```

However, this has the potential to be extremely inefficient, as the map can be really big (10k+ elements).

So, is there a better way to replicate the `std::vector` approach with `std::map`?

Comment: `std::end(full) + off + num_elms` makes no sense

Comment: The problem with your first try with maps is, that the map iterator is not a Random Access Iterator, so you can not add a number to the iterator. But you can advance the iterator with this function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next

Comment: Aside: copying the elements to sub maps seems like a waste, can you identify pairs of `map::const_iterator` instead for the threads to look at?

Comment: I deleted my answer using `std::next` because your question seems fundamentally broken. If you find yourself using indexes with `std::map`, then `std::map` isn't the right tool.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thanks for catching that, it should naturally be `std::begin()`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili the logic that will manipulate the map doesn't use indexes of cause. That uses keys. It is because I want each thread to operate on a given number of elements from the map

Comment: @Caleth I had not thought about that option... thanks :)

Comment: @LarsNielsen I suggest you use a sorted vector instead.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili can you ellaborate on why?

Comment: @LarsNielsen `std::map` is usually implemented as a binary tree. It provides `O(log(n))` insertion in the middle and guarantees that iterators are not invalidated when inserting/removing elements. But it is very inefficient in every other case. A vector is likely to use less memory, work faster, and it works more naturally with ranges in your use case. You don't even need to copy the ranges, you can just pass 2 pointers/iterators to each thread. Be sure to avoid [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) if you plan writing to the elements.

Comment: I see your point. The only issue here is that the group I achieve with the key-value structure is important :/ I will try and rethink my approach. Thanks for elaborating @AyxanHaqverdili

Comment: @LarsNielsen you can keep your key-value pairs. Imagine something like `vector<pair<key, value>>`. Then you sort it and use binary search.

Comment: point taken thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach would be to use one of the execution policies added in C++17, like [`std::execution::parallel_policy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t). In the example below, the instance `std::execution::par` is used:

```
#include <execution>

    // ...

    std::for_each(std::execution::par, full.begin(), full.end(), [](auto& p) {
        // Here you are likely using a thread from a built-in thread pool
        auto& vec = p.second;
        // do work with "vec"
    });
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea. Could even use `par_unseq` most of the time.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Thanks. I agree about `par_unseq` and I've compared `par` and `par_unseq` a few times and I've always gotten very similar performance improvements (compared to running it in sequence as normal) - but, in theory it could be faster.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight adaption, you can reasonably easily pass ranges to `print_map`, and divide up your map by calling `std::next` on an iterator.

```
// Minimal range-for support
template <typename Iter>
struct Range {
    Range (Iter b, Iter e) : b(b), e(e) {}
    Iter b;
    Iter e;

    Iter begin() const { return b; }
    Iter end() const { return e; }
};

// some shorter aliases
using Map = std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>;
using MapView = Range<Map::const_iterator>;

// not necessarily the whole map
void print_map(MapView map) {
    for (const auto& [key, value] : map)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << "\nvalues\n";
        for (const auto& elm : value)
        {
            std::cout << "\t" << elm << "\n"; 
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Map full;

    full["aa"] = {"aa", "aaaa", "aabb"};
    full["bb"] = {"bb", "bbbbb", "bbaa"};
    full["cc"] = {"cc", "cccc", "ccbb"};
    full["dd"] = {"dd", "dd", "ddcc"};

    // can still print the whole map
    print_map({ map.begin(), map.end() });

    size_t num_elms = 2;
    size_t num_full_views = full.size() / num_elms;
    
    std::vector<MapView> views;

    auto it = full.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_full_views; ++i) {
        auto next = std::next(it, num_elms);
        views.emplace_back(it, next);
        it = next;
    }

    if (it != full.end()) {
        views.emplace_back(it, full.end());
    }

    for (auto view : views) {
        print_map(view);
    }
}
```

In C++20 (or with another ranges library), this can be simplified with `std::ranges::drop_view` / `std::ranges::take_view`.

```
using MapView = decltype(std::declval<Map>() | std::ranges::views::drop(0) | std::ranges::views::take(0));


for (size_t i = 0; i < map.size(); i += num_elms) {
    views.push_back(map | std::ranges::views::drop(i) | std::ranges::views::take(num_elms));
}
```

Comment: Imagine that `std::next` is uses a for-loop. Then the vector::emplace_back uses another for-loop to iterate over the same elements. It's just such an inefficient thing.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili "such an inefficient thing" can still be "fast enough"

Comment: Sure, but `map` is obviously not designed to do this. It's kinds of an abuse.

Comment: We are iterating the full map a total of twice. I'd hardly call that abuse. `map` is designed to be used as a range. `drop_view` and `take_view` are not novel ideas.